# Editing the Nmap dictionary?

Tags: brute-force, nmap

When using the Nmap scripts for brute-forcing, let's take an example of FTP brute-force available here : https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/ftp-brute.html

How do i access the Nmap dictionary list of this script? for the need of editing it !

I would appreciate any help .

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you linked lists the script arguments that can be passed, one of which is the `passdb` argument. This is documented in the [`unpwdb` library documentation](https://nmap.org/nsedoc/lib/unpwdb.html#script-args). The default list is in Nmap's data directory under `nselib/data/passwords.list`, but you can pass the name of any newline-separated file with `--script-args 'passdb=example.txt'`.